# Overriding init method in Swift for Objective-C class with naming conflict

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud

I am trying to subclass the `IBMDataObject` from the Mobile Data SDK on Bluemix. The `IBMData` framework in written in Objective-C, so the init method I am trying to override, looks like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithClass:(NSString *)classname;
```

Using this in Swift, it gets converted to:

```
init!(withClass classname: String!) {
    super.init(withClass: classname)
}
```

This must conflict with a naming convention check in Swift, because I then get the error:

[image]

Having the word class in the init method name seems to cause an issue because the auto-fix deletes `withClass` and puts in the keyword `class`.

I am not sure if there is a workaround for this, maybe a warning suppression? Or does the `IBMDataObject` init method need to change it's name?

Comment: just using `init(className: String)` doesn't work? This should be the right way how the bridging from Obj-C to swift works...

Comment: If I use the init in that way, I get a runtime fatal error: `fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(withClass:)' for class 'My_Project.MediaItemInfo'`. I get warning if I call super init any other way but this: `super.init(withClass: classname)`

Comment: I believe the conversion would be the following:

`init(classname: String)`

I do not see any build warnings in my project when using the above, but have also not tried using it at runtime

Comment: So I tried `init(classname: String)` with `super.init(withClass: classname)` and I get the same issue. Formerly in Swift < 1.1, the following worked: `override init(\`class\` classname: String!) { super.init(\`class\`:classname)  }`

Comment: In addition, building the Swift project in this [repo](https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/bluelist-mobiledata/overview) has the same issue with Swift 1.2 in Xcode 6.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same error, fixed it by changing the override method with:

```
required override init() {
    super.init(withClass: "Item")
}
```

Since the init method is required to receive a string argument.
    <<(NSString *)classname;>>

Also changed the init method to:

```
init(className: String){
    super.init(withClass: className)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think it was adding `super.init(withClass: "Item")` that did the trick, thanks!